# Display fails about ~2 minutes. Just stops outputting to monitors

Tags: graphics-card, external-display

I am experiencing a strange problem...

I am on a windows 7 system with dual monitors. Same config for about 2 years... nothing has changed.

Just now, the monitors stopped responding ( as though they aren't getting a signal at all) after about 1 or 2 minutes. I tried rebooting many times, and the same thing happens every time. This isn't windows related, as even when I enter the bios on startup, the display just stops after a few minutes.

Since nothing has changed, I am totally stumped.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If both monitors stop, regardless of OS, consider that the graphical card (plug in or the on motherboard one) is broken. Test that by first testing the monitors on another computer.

Comment: Testing other monitors now. So if the next montors fail, shall I assume a bum graphics card?  If that is the case, what physically happens to the cards that makes them fail?  Just looking for some troubleshooting guidance so that I don't go out and spend unnecessary funds on a new card.

Comment: Could be plain broken. Or failed cooling, or a loose connector. However the goal is to determine which component is broken. And since I do not assume that to monitors broke at the same time it is either the graphical card or the OS. And it is not the OS since the BIOS has the same behaviour.

Comment: Good point. The testing of other monitors found that the issue persisted, so that rules out the monitors. Testing alternate graphics card now.

Comment: Reinstalled the original card after blowing out the dust, etc. Seems to be working so far. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction. Will post the full troubleshooting steps in 8 hours after I am allowed to do so.

Comment: So it failed again. I went to physically remove the card, and it was burning hot to the touch. Turns out that the graphics card fan  failed, causing the hardware to overheat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a bad fan on the video card causing it to overheat. Had to replace the card, and now we're all set.